# How to organize code in iOS project if I try to develop app 100% programmatically?

Tags: ios, uitableview, architecture, viewcontroller, appdelegate

I just recently started with iOS development. The only thing is that I am trying to develop apps (Models, Views, Controllers) 100% programmatically, which means that I do not use Storyboards or xib files. I do it because I need to get an understanding how app works internally: where it starts, how it goes from one view controller to another, how everything is connected, where from all the files are loaded. Of course, later I'll start all the features XCode suggests.
However, I think there is a problem that I am constantly hitting and for which I could not find an answer since there are not that many sample codes published for apps created programmatically. Usually, an example explains how to use, let's say a UINavigationBar or UITableView, but puts all of them into *AppDelegate.m* file, what I do not really like since it kills all the idea of MVC. So, here is my question:
I figured out that app starts execution at *main.m* file and then goes to *AppDelegate.m*. So, I put my window and rootViewController initialization there. But, *which view controller should I put really as a root view controller?* I am not creating anything fancy, and usually I am satisfied with default implementations, so it does not really make sense to inherit from base class. So, what should I do in this case? Where should I put all my configurations and settings? Should I really put it in my *AppDelegate* file?
Here is an example. I am trying to create Checklist app:

**main.m:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,     NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

**(AppDelegate.h has default interface), so AppDelegate.m:**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainTableViewController.h"    
@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

[self setWindow:[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]];

MainTableViewController *tablevc = [[MainTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
[[self window] setRootViewController:tablevc];
return YES;
}
@end
```

**MainTableViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MainTableViewController : UITableViewController
@end
```

**MainTableViewController.m:**

```
#import "MainTableViewController.h"
@implementation MainTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // put my code here?
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section {
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 0;
}
@end
```

What if I want to set actually different views depending on the content? Let's say if the tableview is empty I want to put a UILabel with text "No to-do item", and if there is at least one entry, I want to display the tableview? Should I be just handling different views in *ViewDidLoad* and *ViewWillAppear* ?
Thank you.

Comment: You could. But that would only make things complicated in some cases. For example, in your example, you implemented a `UITableViewController`. If your model returns no results, you can simply add a `UILabel` in the `viewController`'s view as subview, and set it not hidden. If your model returns a list of objects (in your example as a list of to-do list items), you simply set that label hidden, and use `UITableView` datasource methods to populate a table.

Comment: @Jing , okay, so how could I organize code and not overcomplicate it? Thanks!

Comment: What code you show is fine, but it's hard to answer a theoretical question like this; there is no best way, and how you do it depends on what you're trying to accomplish. In the example you give, I would always show the table view, but populate the label in the first cell with "No to-do item" if you don't have any data to show (you could have a special cell for that if you want).